# Web application with pearltree like interface

Tags: math, editor

The [pearltree](http://www.pearltrees.com/) site has an interesting interface. I would be interested in such an interface as a library (Java, Python, HTML5?) for an online editor.

The project uses [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html) and states in [this old blog post](http://blog.pearltrees.com/?page_id=12494) that HTML5 performs worse.

I am asking this question in the context of [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367411/online-math-tool-for-equation-visualisation) on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try D3 JS http://d3js.org/

Here is an example using D3 and nodes, http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html

[image]

Comment: looks neat; I will check it out and mark your answer accordingly; just don't have the time right now; 10x